# How to use nestjs @ResolveField Decorator Properly?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, typegraphql, nestjs-graphql

I am creating one `nestjs graphql api`. I write all function correctly. But when I need to add `@ResolveField` into `@Resolver` Decorator, I am facing one problem. Can any tell me when I need two @ResolveField in one @Resolver, then How can I add it?

Here is Category Entity-(`category.entity.ts`)

```
@ObjectType()
export class Category {
    @Field(() => ID, { nullable: false })
    id: ObjectId;
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    name: string;
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
    description: string;
    @Field(() => [Subcategory], { nullable: true })
    subCategory: Subcategory[];
    @Field(() => Date, { nullable: false })
    createdAt: DateScalar;
    @Field(() => Date, { nullable: false })
    updatedAt: DateScalar;
}
```

And Here is Subcategory Entity (`sub-category.entity.ts`)-

```
@ObjectType()
export class Subcategory {
    @Field(() => ID, { nullable: false })
    id: ObjectId;
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    name: string;
    @Field(() => Category, { nullable: false })
    category: Category;
    @Field(() => Date, { nullable: false })
    createdAt: DateScalar;
    @Field(() => Date, { nullable: false })
    updatedAt: DateScalar;
}
```

And This is Resolver (`category.resolver.ts`)-

```
@Resolver()
export class CategoryResolver {
    //Constructor
    constructor(private readonly categoryService: CategoryService) { }

    //Get All Category
    @Query(() => [Category], { name: "getCategories" })
    categories() {
        return this.categoryService.categories()
    }

    //Get All Sub Category
    @Query(() => [Subcategory], { name: "getSubCategories" })
    subCategories() {
        return this.categoryService.subCategories();
    }
    
    //Resolve Field

    //For Category
    @ResolveField("subCategory", () => [Subcategory])
    batchSubCategory(
        @Parent() category: Category
    ) {
        console.log(category);
    }
    //For Subcategory
    @ResolveField("category", () => Category)
    batchCategory(
        @Parent() subCategory: Subcategory
    ) {
        console.log(subCategory)
    }
}
```

Here you can see two `@ResolveField` Decorator. For working This I need to add Entity in `@Resolver` decorator, like-

`@Resolver(Category)`

or

`@Resolver(Subcategory)`

When I give `Category` then One `ResolveField` work perfectly, other is not working. Again When I give `Subcategory` then the other is working perfectly, but first one is not working. But When I give together then it gives me error-

`@Resolver(Category, Subcategory)`

Please help me. I need it Please help me. I can't solve it for 3 days. I search for the same things over internet but not finding any solutions.

Comment: Split the 2 field resolvers into 2 different (class) resolvers. One annotated with `@Resolver(Category)`, and the other with `@Resolver(Subcategory)`